# Validation issues in cloned row in table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have cloned row form existing row in a table,i have gave validations for first row using jquery.validate.unobtrusive but it is not working properly for cloned row

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in your view and validate for client site.

For example if you have table you can use scripts some like:

Before form submit you can use:

```
var filterTable = $('#tableID').find('tr').length;
if (filterTable != 1) {
    CheckFilterNameField(); // Use function
}
```

This function

```
function CheckFilterNameField() {
var $namefield = $('.filterPanel tr .namefield');
$namefield.each(function () {
    if ("your conditions")
        $(this).addClass('error');
    else
        $(this).removeClass('error');
  });
}
```

If you will be have class error on the element in your table page can't load and in the specific item for example will be red or you can show alert about error in your form.